# Programmatically taking a screenshot in Android of another Window

Tags: java, android

So, I currently have this code:

```
private void takeScreenshot()
{

    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    try
    {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Screenshots/" + now + ".jpg";
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{imageFile.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

        //openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code is being called on a notification press, that is being generated elsewhere in the app. The code does take a screenshot but is only screenshotting the application window regardless of where you are actually looking. So, I want to take a screenshot of another window whilst calling this function through a notification. Is this possible?

P.S. I've also added a link to a Youtube video where I demonstrate this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FLnTOqTorQ

Comment: I have not tried it, but I highly doubt this is possible as it would be a huge security risk. If an app would be able to create screenshots via a background service and maybe send it to a server without root access it would be "easy" to create a spionage software

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work to get the screenshoot of webview:

```
private void takeScreenshootOfWebview(){
      Bitmap   mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView(captureScreenShot);
      createImage(mbitmap);

}


// First create bitmap of your view
    public Bitmap getBitmapOFWebView(View v) {
        View rootview = v.getRootView();
        rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = rootview.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap1;
    }

// Then save in file
        public void createImage(Bitmap bmp) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    "/capturedscreenandroid.jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: private void takeScreenshootOfWebview(){
      Bitmap   mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView(captureScreenShot);
      createImage(mbitmap);

}

Where are you getting captureScreenshot from and why is it being parsed into that method call?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 5.0+, use the media projection APIs (e.g., `MediaProjectionManager`) to request permission to take screenshots, then be able to actually take those screenshots.

Comment: Can you recommend any good tutorials for it? It's not an area of the API I'm hugely familiar with

Comment: @TVerran: I do not know of any tutorials, though I have not looked for any recently. I have [a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter), covered in [a chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/screenshots-and-screen-recordings) of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android).